# Override target_compile_options via cmake command line

Tags: cmake

I'm switching our project from using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` over to the `target_compile_options()` for better granularity. However, our project allows users to override our default `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` by specifying their own, which are appended to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` within the `CMakeLists.txt`.

For Example:

```
  if(DEFINED USER_CXX_FLAGS)  
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${USER_CXX_FLAGS}")
  endif()
```

and `cmake -DUSER_CXX_FLAGS=="-Wno-error"`.

However, with the `target_compile_options` method of specifying options, this no longer works. Since `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` occur before the flags set in `target_compile_options`.

i.e.

```
c++ ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${FLAGS_FROM_TARGET_COMPILE_OPTIONS} file.cc`
```

Is there a way to allow users to specify different flags while using `target_compile_options()`?

Comment: You don't need that code, let your users provide `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly.

Comment: not sure I understand: the user can already add new flag with target_add_options, and as they come after the main one, they are the one used, aren't they?

Comment: We needed it originally because our project set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS directly as well. So if the user specified `-Wno-error` and we append `-Werror` afterwards, we override their settings.

Comment: @OznOg I am trying to find a solution that doesn't edit the `CMakeLists.txt` directly.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question either. You want to let them customize the build flags or not? If yes, then you don't need to do anything. If no, then you need to clear this variable (but that would be unexpected)

Comment: I want them to be able to specify overrides to the build flags via the commandline `cmake` invocation. I don't want them to have to edit the `CMakeList.txt` directly, if I can help it.

Comment: So you don't want them to append flags, you want them to completely override your flags?

Comment: No, I want them to be able to append flags that could override the flags specified by the project. Thus they need to come after all the flags set internally.

Comment: then just do `target_compile_options(YourTarget ${Your_Flags} ${USER_CXX_FLAGS})` and either warn users to not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or clear it to make sure they won't use it.

Comment: The only flags that belong in the CMakeLists.txt file and _especially_ in `target_compile_options` are those without which your code **cannot** compile. That does not include `-Werror`. This impedance mismatch is the root cause of your issue. `-Werror` is _functionally optional_ and should be injected via `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` by your CI (toolchains and presets make this more convenient), not imposed by the build system itself.

Comment: @AlexReinking Do you have a reference for why that should be the case? Yes, it is not required to build, but we want standard compliant code and don't want to keep checking CI builds to make sure what we write is good.

Comment: Have you heard of CMake presets? They're a convenient place for storing common sets of optional flags (like `-Werror`) without forcing them on your users. Also, what kind of reference are you looking for? `-Werror` is _famously_ bad for hardcoding in a build system. Look at the fracas with the Linux kernel recently, or the Gentoo packaging guidelines, etc.

Comment: A reference saying putting flags that are not required for compiling shouldn't go in a `target_compile_flags` etc...  I haven't heard of the presets, but it seems like it is fairly new (3.19?) and won't be ideal since a lot of users are still using old cmakes.

Comment: @Moop It won't hurt to add presets; That's just a json file to place next to the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`. Adding this file won't break builds with older cmake versions, but it's convenient, if a recent version is available. If you want to support similar functionality for older versions, you could implement similar functionality by providing cache initialization scripts that can be added via `-C` option or toolchain files. As for hardcoding flags. This indeed should be kept to a minimum to provide maximum flexibility to the user; do you know for sure all, compiler support this flag?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and draw on some of the comments above to put together a more comprehensive answer to this.  Because, basically, there isn't a way to do exactly what you want, and asking this question means your build system isn't set up in a very best-practices-compliant way.  But, I think there is a way to get to the spirit of what you want.

In CMake, there are basically three categories of compiler flags:

1. Flags that are required for the build.  These are things that you or end users would never want to change, and which should get exported along with the library when installed.  Examples:

- `-Wno-some-specific-warning` to suppress a warning for some piece of code
- `-fno-exceptions` to turn off exceptions for code that is not designed to work with them.

2. Flags that you want to set to a default for, but then allow users to change using the cache editor or the GUI.  This could be something like:

- `-march` and `-mtune` for setting the architecture of a CPU build
- Warning flags like `-Werror` or `-Wextra`, which you want people to be able to turn off if wanted (though it can be clearer to add a separate option for those)

3. User-provided flags, where you just want to take in flags from the user and apply them everywhere.

---

For each of these categories, there are several different ways to implement them.

For required flags (case 1), these can be set at the directory level (`add_compile_options()`), the target level (`target_compile_options()`), or even the source level using properties.  Or, you can set them globally, using something like

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -myflag")
```

Note that this actually shadows the cache variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS with a local variable (CMake why?), so you can still set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` on the command line and it will have the effect of combining any passed flags with the flags you set in code.

For flags where you want to provide an editable default (case 2), the most correct way to do this is to add them to the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT`.  This is a special variable that, the very first time `project()` or `enable_languages()` is called during a fresh configuration, is loaded into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.  This way, the user can see the flags in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` when they edit the CMake cache, and can modify them as desired.

Note that this does have the problem of being global -- it can only be set in the top-level project.  So this method is usually used only for toolchain flags when cross-compiling.

For just accepting user-supplied flags, you can just make your own cache variable, like

```
set(USER_CXX_FLAGS "" CACHE STRING "Put any additional flags to add here")
```

Then, tell users to add flags to this variable if they need custom flags.  Note that this is nonstandard project behavior, and people will probably just add stuff to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` unless you tell them differently.

You can then take this variable and append it to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, or to the directory-scope flags as follows:

```
separate_arguments(USER_CXX_FLAGS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND "${USER_CXX_FLAGS}")
add_compile_options(${USER_CXX_FLAGS_LIST})
```

Note that separate_arguments() is required because add_compile_options() needs a ;-separated list, not a string.

---

Now, let's talk about overriding.  Compile flag precedence in CMake goes from global (first, so least precedence), to directory-scope, to target-scope, finally to source-file-scope.  It sounds like your problem is that you have flags applied with target precedence, that you want to override with user flags passed in as a variable.

The easiest solution to this problem, as @alex-reinking pointed out, is to simply take the flags that need to be overridden, and move them to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or to the directory scope.  Basically, since target-scope flags should only be used for flags in case 1, I am challenging why you feel those need to be overridden at all.  I have a feeling that if you went through all of the target-scope flags, you could separate them into two categories: "can be global/directory-level, may want to be overridden", and "must be target-level, wouldn't ever need to be overridden".

If you are able to move all of the flags that might have to be overridden into the global or directory scope, you can then use one of the methods above to override them.

But, if you really want to override target-scope flags with arbitrary user flags, there is a way: you just need to attach the flags to the same target as the flags you want to override.  Like, if you have:

```
add_library(MyLibrary MySource.cpp)
target_compile_options(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    -flag-that-I-want-to-override)
```

you would change it to:

```
set(USER_CXX_FLAGS "" CACHE STRING "Put any additional flags to add here")
separate_arguments(USER_CXX_FLAGS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND "${USER_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_library(MyLibrary MySource.cpp)
target_compile_options(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    -flag-that-I-want-to-override
    ${USER_CXX_FLAGS_LIST})
```

That should accomplish the goal of overriding the flags.  Note that you'd need to attach ${USER_CXX_FLAGS_LIST} to every target that has flags you want to override.